# The output of a shallow multilayer network, with linear activation function in each of the neurons, is linear in the weights -> FALSE?

Tags: machine-learning, math, neural-network

Can anyone prove to me why the above sentence is FALSE?
I have the feeling that being all linear units I can always write W(Linear) = Y for any W, but the teacher says it's False and quoted a student that said:

> The output y of said shallow network is y=sum(v)* sum(wTx +b), so we have the product of the weights v and w inside the output. So the output is non linear in respect to the weights

Could anyone be more precise/analytical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following neural network:

```
x1 --  h1
   \/     \ y
   /\     /
x2 --  h2
```

Corresponding to the following equations:

```
h1 = w11 x1 + w12 x2
h2 = w21 x1 + w22 x2
y = v1 h1 + v2 h2
```

Here the weights are `w11, w12, w21, w22, v1, v2`.

Combining the three equations, we get:

```
y = v1 w11 x1 + v1 w12 x2 + v2 w21 x1 + v2 w22 x2
```

Hence we can say that `y` is a **bilinear** function of `(w11, w12, w21, w22) and (v1, v2)`, but we cannot say that `y` is a **linear** function of `(w11, w12, w21, w22, v1, v2)`.

Comment: Did I understand well if I tell that if x = (w11, w12, w21, w22, v1, v2) then
>f(az) != af(z) then is not linear?

Comment: x1 and x2 are the input of the neural network; writing x = (w11, w12, w21, w22, v1, v2) is confusing. But yes, when you multiply every weight by a constant, y is multiplied by the square of that constant, therefore y is not a linear function of (w11, w12, w21, w22, v1, v2). However, if you multiply only (w11, w12, w21, w22) or only (v1, v2) by a constant, then y is multiplied by that constant; hence y is a linear function of (w11, w12, w21, w22) and a linear function of (v1, v2).